# wkhtmltopdf integrated with php doesnt work

Tags: php

I try to use wkhtmltopdf to convert html file to pdf, and it works correctly when I use it from command line, but when I try to integrate it with php, it doesn't work

```
<?php
echo exec('whoami');
$cd = "cd C:/www/genpdf";
exec($cd);
$command = "C:/Program Files (x86)/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf -O landscape C:/www/genpdf/index-5.html C:/www/genpdf/index-5.pdf";
exec($command);

if (file_exists("C:/www/genpdf/index-5.pdf")) {
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="index-5.pdf"');
readfile("C:/www/genpdf/index-5.pdf");
}

else {
    echo "error";
}
```

?>

`echo exec('whoami');` shows me `nt authority\бЁбвҐ` line
and then I get `error` line in browser and no pdf file.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting may be disable to run system command from php script. So please first verify it. Also try to use system command in place of exec.

Comment: How can I check if system commands are enebled in php script? what command Should I use instead of `exec` ?

Comment: check "safe_mode" setting is enabled or not in php_ini

Comment: `safe_mode` = off and with `system` command it works, thanks a lot for help.